# Has anyone used YodaQA for natural language processing?

Tags: ai-design, natural-language-processing

Has anyone used YodaQA for natural language processing? How easy is it to link to a document database other than Wikipedia?

We're thinking we can create a bot to use AI to analyze our developer and user documentation and provide a written or spoken answer in reply. YodaQA comes linked to Wikipedia for starters, but we'd need to link to our own source info. I'm trying to get an idea of the development time required to set up the AI and then to link to the database.

Comment: i am interested in the exact same topic: creating a question answering system for a programming API. in my case, the API is the Revit API. i have heaps of existing documentation and would like to implement a question answering system based on that. i would be very interested in hearing what you find out your end, and also in any answers to this question anyone can provide. thank you! ontology sources for Revit API: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/virtues-of-reproduction-research-mep-settings-ontology.html#8

Comment: Look at [yodaqa issue #17 Domain Adaptations](https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa/issues/17) for a pretty extensive discussion of this and closely related topics.